# Create object from its foreign key's object

Tags: python, django

I have two objects: Restaurant and Review, a Review has a foreign key Restaurant (one-to-many relationship). In my views.py, these two classes make me concern the most: RestaurantDetailView(show detail view of a Restaurant), and ReviewCreate(create a review).

My point is I want to create a button "Write a Review" my Restaurant Detail page that send a request to create a Review, but that Review has to contain the foreign key of the Restaurant where I sent request from. Any suggestion of how I should do this?

For reference:

```
class RestaurantDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    template_name = 'service/detail-restaurant.html'

class ReviewCreate(CreateView):
    model = Review
    fields = ['title', 'description']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        review = form.save(commit=False)
        review.restaurant = self.request.user
        return super(ReviewCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You can create a url that contains the restaurant id, something like this `create/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/review/$` where `pk` is the restaurant id. There, you render your `Review` creation form and during the processing of the form, you extract the pk of the restaurant. That's one way of doing it, there are certainly different methods as well.

Comment: @ledao you could check this tutorial of how to use urls with pk 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-4